# baseUrl and trailing slash Craft 3

Tags: config, configuration

Despite setting baseUrl alias with trailing slash it appears it gets stripped off in Craft 3.

```
CRAFTENV_BASE_URL="https://domain.test/"
```

```
  'aliases' => [
      '@siteUrl' => getenv('CRAFTENV_SITE_URL'),
      '@baseUrl' => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_URL'),
      '@basePath'   => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_PATH')
    ],
```

template

```
 {% set baseUrl = alias('@baseUrl') %}
```

which renders

```
https://domain.test
```

and breaks my craft 2 template links to stylesheets etc.

I can fix with

```
 {% set baseUrl = alias('@baseUrl') ~ '/' %}
```

but can't help but think trailing slash was compulsory in Craft 2.